# Apple Mach-O Librarian Error

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, cocos2d-x

I download the cocos2d-x project from our SVN, but an problem happened when I opened it with Xcode, error information is as follows:

```
/Applications/Xcode .app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC 
/Applications/Xcode .app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lwebp
/Applications/Xcode .app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lwebp is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Applications/Xcode .app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

**can anyone give me some advice, thank you very much.**

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
@trojanfoe, you're right.
sry didn't read the last part. I check my cocos2s-x project and give you a right anwer.

[edit 2]

OK, I tested my project and the empty from github. 
Where have you downloaded the SVN from?
And what is your Xcode Version?

have you used this repository: [get cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x)?
If not, go ahead and clone it, open the `build>cocos2d_samples.xcodeproj` and select `Test cpp iOS` > `iPhone` > `iOS 7.0` for example and run the build.
 This should work at least.

Comment: Nah - you can see that his linker line is corrupted as it thinks `-lwebp` should be an object file.